# Validating MVC 4 form without Unobtrusive ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate my form without using Unobtrusive Validation becauase my validation is a little more complicated than average.  What is needed to accomplish this?  Just include the Validation.js script into my file and writing out the jquery code?  That is what I have accomplished so far...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#formSearchByMRN").validate({
        rules: {
            MRN: { required: true, minLength: 6 }
        },
        messages: {
            MRN: 'Please Enter a Valid MRN'
        }
    });
});
```

However, whenever I submit my form nothing is validated?  Here is my form...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchByMRN", "SearchPatients", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formSearchByMRN" }))
 {
    <p>
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.Label("MRN#", new { @for = "MRN" })<br />@Html.TextBox("MRN","", new { id = "MRN" })</li>            

        <li>@Html.Label("MRNDrop", new { @for = "MRNDrop" })<br /> @Html.DropDownList("MRNDrop", (List<SelectListItem>)TempData["MRNLIST"], new { id = "MRNDrop" })</li>
    </ul>
    </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Search by MRN" id="submitMRN"/>                                                                                                              
 }
```

What am I missing.  I have my jquery Valition script in my _layout.cshtml file.

Comment: That looks ok, check that the validation plugin is included and that the unobtrusive validation script isn't included.  Check for any script errors, if you are still having problems maybe post some rendered html.

Comment: After testing, I just realized that I have a submit function which I have an event.preventDefault?  How can I mitigated the functionality?  Because the form still submits and I still get the validation message?